# Servlet: Cannot instantiate javaURLContextFactory only if load-on-startup

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

In Tomcat 7 (JDK 1.7) I have a servlet that in load on startup returns this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
```

but if I call same servlet from browser it runs.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on the servlet init() method that is invoked on start up only. Seems you are missing one or more JAR files from the classpath

Tomcat 6 and 7 support servlet 2.5 standard.  The standard includes a better way to do web-server-bootstrap actions, through the [ServletContextListener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface.

Tomcat 7 supports servlet 3.0 standard, where you can annotate your class to avoid web.xml configuratiuon

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebListener
public class BootstrapTheWebServer implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)   {
        // invoked on web server start up 
        // event.getServletContext() to get servlet context
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
      // invoked on web server shutdown 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below dependency in your class path:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```